# JQuery Closest element in same node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JQuery, how can I select the **closest** element of a certain type that is in the same node as the element I am using?

**For example:**
From the `$('#errorDate')` and want to select the closest `span`?

```
<td width="318" class="body">
    <input name="errorDate" type="text" id="errorDate" class="txtInputs" />
    <span class="errorDes"id="errorDes"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: For the code supplied, `.next()` is the obvious answer. However, seeing as you are mentioning **closest** - maybe your actual use case is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for selecting this,

```
var firstspan=$('#errorDate').closest('td').find('span:first-of-type');
```

**or**

```
var firstspan=$('#errorDate').closest('td').find('span.errorDes');
```

**or**

```
var firstspan=$('#errorDate').next('span.errorDes');
```

**or**

```
var firstspan=$('#errorDate').closest('td').find('span:first');
```

Comment: this is wrong, the first one goes to the parent in an unnecessary search with closest then finds the first span child which can be far from the #errorDate in some cases, the second uses a class which can be spotted directly with parent child but obviously that is not what the OP asked for, the third is useless as it will select the next element if it was a span with that class, the forth does the same as the first .. not even close to what the OP asked for .. unless if the OP meant something else

Answer (score 2):

[updated with fiddle]

if you want to select the first next sibling go for :

```
$('#errorDate').nextAll('span:first')
```

and for first previous :

```
$('#errorDate').prevAll('span:first')
```

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/gZcFg/2/)

Comment: +1 Works very well, just fixed the selectors from class to ID (to match the question's markup)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
$('#errorDate').next('span')
```

Or Just

```
$('#errorDate').next()
```

Comment: +1 Just note: the 'span' argument here is not needed. Rather than searching for the next span, this code is only going to return something *if* the next sibling element *is* a span.

Answer (score 2):

for more details, if you're interested take a look at https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-nearest